# External hdmi monitor stopped working (undetected)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor, external-monitor

As today, my external monitor is not detected any more by my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop :(

- I know the monitor and cable are working correctly since it works on a different laptop.
- `Settings -> Devices -> Displays` shows only the laptop screen.
- No matter if I log in with wayland or xorg, same result.
- Keyboard `key` to switch display mode does nothing (apparently)

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

`lspci | grep -iE "display|vga"` ouptut:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
09:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev ff)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using 17.10 actually, "16.10" was a typo.

Comment: Your question was closed as being about an unsupported Ubuntu version, but your answer suggests that the problem now can't be reproduced, so I don't think there is any benefit in reopening it at this stage.

Comment: Fair enough. For what it's worth, looks like my bios has been misbehaving due to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not sure how this fixed it but I went to the bios and change display from "auto detect" to "external hdmi", then started to work again.